# How can I for-each all documents in a collection? Firebase (exceeds limit)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I have a collection with about 400,000 documents.

I would like to foreach all of them with conditions to modify some of them and also register them in elasticsearch (add them to another system, basically do a post)?

How could I do this?
- Maybe creating some kind of foreach on my intranet? (I use an angular/fire app to manage some stuffs)
- Or create a firebase function for this?

Either way, I don't know how I could go through them all safely. Any idea or suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to have to write a program (you can run it on your machine) to make the query, iterate the documents in the result set, and do something for each document.  I don't think there's going to be any shortcuts here.  Is there something in particular you're having problems with?

Comment: Well, then as you said I have to implement something on my angular app to implement this kind of migration and run it in my machine. I know there is a limit so I'm not sure how to manage this with a big amount of data. @DougStevenson

Comment: You don't have to use Angular.  You can write a program in any of the languages with SDKs provided Firestore (which is a lot).

Answer (score 0):

You are right you should use for each method because for each doesnt return thats why its a faster than other methods of ES 6 7. And other thing is start some coding and experience the speed.